# Linker path not found

Tags: gcc, makefile, cygwin, rpc

Currently I am working on GnuWin32 rpcgen tool on Windows 10. My files get compiled and I am able to generate .o files for client and server. But It fails in the linking process. I am running following makefile by make -f Makefile. I am using cygwin tool on windows.

```
# Compiler flags 
CC = gcc
CFLAGS += -g 
LDLIBS += -lnsl
RPCGENFLAGS =
```

I am getting following error:

```
gcc -g -o ipg_rpc_client ipg_rpc_clnt.o ipg_rpc_client.o ipg_rpc_xdr.o -lnsl
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lnsl: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile.ipg_rpc:41: ipg_rpc_client] Error 1
```

please help in solving this error. From last week I am struggling on this.

Comment: You have to use the cygwin setup to search for `libnsl` and install it.

Comment: there is no libnsl in cygwin, so I installed tirpc and changed flag to -ltirpc and it is working perfectly.

Comment: When I search for _libnsl_, I get a package named _libnsl2_, which is available in version 1.2.0-1. Perhaps you can try it using a different mirror? BTW, I'm using the 64-bit-version of Cygwin.

Comment: yes I am also using the same version 64 -bit. I will check 1.2.0-1 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally the error got solved.

I have downloaded libtirpc-devel from cygwin, and changed my LDLIBS in makefile to -ltirpc.

Now my exes got created.